# How to redirect to other page after successful login in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-route-segment

Hi I am developing one application in angularjs as front end and web api2 as backend. I am new to both angular and web api. I have completed login page in angularjs. As soon as my login successful i want to go to page called Index.cshtml located at Views/Home/index.cshtml. I am trying as below.

This is my controller code.

```
app.controller('Login', function ($scope, LoginService) {
    $scope.Login = function () {
        var sub = {
            User_Name: $scope.User_Name,
            User_Password: $scope.User_Password
        };
        var checkData = LoginService.Login(sub);
        checkData.then(function (data) {
            //want redirection
            var url = '/Home/Index/';
            window.location = url;
            }, function (error) {
            })
        };
});
```

This is my module.js

```
var app;
(function () {
    app = angular.module("Login", []);
})();
```

service.js

```
app.service("LoginService", function ($http) {
    this.Login = function (sub) {
        var credentials = { User_Name: sub.User_Name, User_Password: sub.User_Password };
           $http.post('api/NCT_UsersLogin/', credentials).success(function (response) {  });
    }
});
```

I am trying using window.location but it is not working. May I get some help here? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
 $window.location.href = '/Home/index.html';
```

also inject $window to your controller

```
app.controller('Login', function ($scope, LoginService,$window) {
    $scope.Login = function () {
        var sub = {
            User_Name: $scope.User_Name,
            User_Password: $scope.User_Password
        };
        var checkData = LoginService.Login(sub);
        checkData.then(function (data) {
            //want redirection        
              $window.location.href = '/Home/index.html';
            }, function (error) {
            })
        };
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I found problem in service.js because controll is not coming back to success call in controller.js.

Comment: May i know something i am missing in service.js file?

Comment: you should return from the service

Comment: should i put return response?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$state.go(url)`

Try this

```
app.controller('Login', function ($scope, LoginService, $state) {
    $scope.Login = function () {
        var sub = {
            User_Name: $scope.User_Name,
            User_Password: $scope.User_Password
        };
        var checkData = LoginService.Login(sub);
        checkData.then(function (data) {
            //want redirection
            var url = '/Home/Index/';
            $state.go(url);
            }, function (error) {
            })
        };
```

});

Comment: I dont think OP uses any routing

Comment: $state' is undefined i am getting this error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:

```
window.location = url;
```

in this:

```
window.open("http://www.example.com","_self");
```

You should redirect correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $state.go('/home');

For ex:

```
     $http.post('api/NCT_UsersLogin/', credentials).success(function (response) { 
      //if your response status is success then redirect to another page using 
        $state.go('/home');
     });
```