# oktaSignIn login success but not able to redirect url

Tags: angularjs, okta-api

I created the okta sigin login page using angularjs and I got the response as success for okta api.how to redirect the page after login. I have attached the screenshot below:
   please find the solution....

[image: screenshot]

Comment: please check this link hope it will help you 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42085536/how-to-redirect-to-other-page-after-
successful-login-in-angularjs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to other page after successful login in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42085536/how-to-redirect-to-other-page-after-successful-login-in-angularjs)

Comment: this above link is they are using service,but ia m using okta integration api function for example:  oktaSignIn.renderEl(  { el: '#okta-login-container' },function (res) {if (res.status == 'SUCCESS') { alert("User successfully authenticated");  console.log(res);        }    });

Comment: so inside of this success function alert also not working can you check it

Comment: could u please share your code somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Not able to redirect the page after response success please check the code using angularjs with okta authentication login :

var oktaSignIn = new OktaSignIn({
        authParams: {
            responseType: 'id_token',
            responseMode: 'okta_post_message',
            scopes: ['openid', 'groups'],
           // data : JSON.stringify(data1)
        },
        clientId: OKTA_CLIENT_ID,
        baseUrl: OKTA_ORG_URL,
        //redirectUri: "http://localhost:8080",

```
});
oktaSignIn.renderEl(
    { el: '#okta-login-container' },
    function (res) {
    if (res.status == 'SUCCESS') {
            alert("User successfully authenticated");
            console.log(res);*/
            $location.path("https://www.google.com/");



    }
);
```

Comment: Throwing this error above code :error.errorCode: invalid_request, error.description: The 'redirect_uri' parameter must be an absolute URI that is whitelisted in the client app settings.